# identifying ipywidgets with unique IDs (in python)

Tags: python, widget

Is there a way to add an id to a widget so that clicking the first submit button modifies the value of `responses["set1"]` based on the radio buttons in set 1 and likewise for set 2?

I am dynamically generating the number of sets to display so unfortunately can't hard code.

This code as is doesn't work, but hope it demonstrates the spirit of what I'm looking for.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets # running in google colab
from IPython import display

responses = {"set1": None,
             "set2": None}
options = {"this pos": 1, "this neg": -1}

def radio_buttons(options):
  return widgets.RadioButtons(
          options=options.keys(),
          disabled=False
      )

def set_answers(obj):
  responses[SET_N] = APPROPRIATE RADIO BUTTON VALUE

submit = widgets.Button(description="Submit")

print("set 1")
IPython.display.display(radio_buttons(options))
submit.on_click(set_answers) 
IPython.display.display(submit)##any way to set an id to link to set radio_button.value1?


print("set 2")
IPython.display.display(radio_buttons(options))
submit.on_click(set_answers) 
IPython.display.display(submit) ##any way to set an id to link to set2 radio_button.value?
```